# Как вывести все записи таблицы А и принадлежащей ей таблицы Б по условию в таблице Б

Tags: mysql, doctrine2

На примере:
Есть таблица "Фильмы" и "Жанры", связанные many-to-many. Надо вывести все Жанры Фильма если хотя бы один Жанр совпадает с условием. То есть, выбираются Фильмы по Жанру, но для каждого фильма надо показать не только тот Жанр, который совпал с условием, а все, что с ним связанны.

Все это в Doctrine2 Query Builder.

Upd. 
Запрос на данный момент в виде DQL:

```
SELECT Movies, Movies, MovieGenres FROM Entities\Movies Movies LEFT JOIN Movies.MovieGenres MovieGenres WITH MovieGenres.id IN (:genres) WHERE Movies.id IN (SELECT MovieGenres2.id FROM Entities\MovieGenres MoviesGenres2) GROUP BY Movies, MovieGenres
```

В таком виде выводит у фильма с жанрами "Вестерн", "Драма" при поиске по слову "Вестерн" только жанр "Вестерн", а "Драму" показывает если и по ней тоже искать.

Comment: *Есть таблица "Фильмы" и "Жанры", связанные many-to-many.* Структуры в DDL - в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
SELECT f.name, GROUP_CONCAT(g.name)
FROM films f, genres g, films_genres fg
WHERE f.id = fg.f_id 
  AND g.id = fg.g_id
  AND f.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT fg1.f_id
               FROM films_genres fg1, genres g1
               WHERE g1.id = fg1.g_id
                 AND g1.name IN (@genres_list)) sq
GROUP BY f.name
```

Comment: Тут тоже получается фильтрация по жанрам, а мне нужно вывести все жанры фильма, если один из них в списке genres_list...

Comment: Пробовала? Или просто так сказала?

Comment: Пробовала перевести в Doctrine, но видимо, криво. Сейчас прогнала через MySql PHPMyAdmin возвращает правильно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это перевести в Doctrine - получается что надо запрашивать таблицу films_genres, а она сгенерирована автоматически и не является Entity

Comment: Или нельзя через QueryBuilder, надо вставлять через DQL?